# Can use spring data neo4j to execute query like Jdbcteamplate?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, jdbctemplate

I'm using JdbcTemplate to execute native Cypher query.
It is easy to make a query such as: jdbcTemplate.execute(String query)

And now when I moving to spring data neo4j, I wonder if there is any interface to execute directly String query like JdbcTemplate did?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options.

Because you are using Java, one option is to make use of OGM (a library that can be used independently or is included as a core dependency of Spring Data Neo4j).

OGM provides a session object that has query() and queryForObject() methods.

More information (and examples) can be found in the OGM reference documentation:
https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/3.1/reference/#reference:session:loading-entities